# Harmonic function radial on boundary

Tags: harmonic-functions, laplacian, potential-theory

Let $u$ a harmonic function in $B_{1}(0)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; |x| <1\}$, with $u(x)=v(r)$ in $\partial U$ then $u(x)=v(r)$, $\forall x \in B_1{(0)}$, i.e, a harmonic function radial on unit sphere is radial in its interior.

My idea was to use the principle of maximum, but i imagine it's more than that.

Thanks!

Comment: So, $u$ is a *constant*¬on the unit sphere, right?

Comment: Yes @RobertLewis

Comment: The strong maximum principle asserts in particular thar $\inf _{\partial U}u \leq u(x) \leq \sup _{\partial U}u$, for all $x \in U$ but  $u(x)=v(r)=v(|x|)=v(1) in \partial U$, then $v(x)=v(1)$  for all $x \in B_{1}(0)$?

Comment: It's hard to read your comment can you fix the $LaTeX$?  Oh . . . thanks!

Comment: Yes, that looks right, but I need to think about it.  $u$ may be a constant.

Comment: OK, so we agree that $u$ must be constant. If you want radial dependence, you need to allow $u$ to have a singularity somewhere in the ball.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}$ is harmonic in $B_{1}(0)$ , it is radial and $f\equiv 1$ in $\partial B_{1}(0)$ , but f it is not constant in $B_{1}(0)$